# Xcode will run the Unity app on device, but when I run the built app, the black screen will appear

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

environment:

- Develop OS:macOS Catalina 10.15.5
- Xcode:11.5
- Device OS: iPhone 7 Plus (iOS 13.5.1)
- Unity : 2019.3.9f

I built the iOS app with Unity.

When I play on the Running on device on Xcode, the app works normally.
However, when I turn off the Xcode and turn on the built app, the black screen comes out and stops.

If I run it on the simulator to check the log, the following log occurs.

```
Could not find and/or execute program specified by service: 86: Bad CPU type in executable: /Users/develop/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/31985C61-CACF-40D6-8A48-A2BA2BAF0DDD/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/EC20344C-A067-4379-A9EA-CE0E42F3C106/make.app/make
Service setup event to handle failure and will not launch until it fires.
Service exited with abnormal code: 78
```

But when I play on the Running on device on Xcode, I can't understand the app running normally.

I tried the Unity version 2018 to figure out the problem, but it works well. However, when I upgraded the Unity version to 2019, the above problem occurs.

I want to know the causes and solutions of these problems in Unity 2019.

Answer (score 0):

On Xcode

Go to Unity-iPhone - Build Phases - Link Binary with Libraries build section

Add UnityFramework.framework

This happens on Unity 2019/2020